# Select items only if they all meet the specific condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables on a Oracle SQL DB.

- **Article (id [PK])**
- **File (id [PK], article_id [FK], insertion_date [DATETIME]).**

I want to select files from articles that are more than 15 days old without adding new files.

For example, if post ID 1 has a file added 10 days ago and another 20 days ago, they should not be returned in the select, but if article 2 has 4 files added more than 15 days ago, it should be returned.

I tried performing a

```
select * from File where insertion_date <= 15 days ago.
```

But post archives that had recent additions continued to be returned.

Comment: Is that the actual SQL statement? Your criteria for each record depends on data in other records. This is tricky and usually requires subqueries. At least it would with Access SQL. I don't know Oracle.

Comment: `select * from files a where not exists (select 1 from files b where insertion_date <= sysdate -15 and a.article_id = b.article_id)`

Comment: SELECT * FROM File a INNER JOIN (SELECT article_id, Max(insertion_date) AS MD FROM File GROUP BY article_id) AS Q
ON a.article_id = Q.article_id WHERE MD<=sysdate-15;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We look for all entries in `files` with insertion_date more than 15 days old, and for each article we check for the existence of a more recent row, we reject if it does:

```
select * 
from files a 
where insertion_date <= sysdate -15
and not exists 
    (
    select 1 
    from files b 
    where a.article_id = b.article_id
    and b.insertion_date > a.insertion_date
    )
```